# Trouble with double (two-component) picker view

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Im working with a double (two-component) picker view. When I run it shows me the double picker view, but the same information in both component's rows.

Here is the code hope you can help me.
I want to show in the first component the array1 and in the second component the array2.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *FirstArray1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
      @"White",@"Whole Wheat",@"Rye",@"Sourdough",@"Seven Grain", nil];
    self.Array1 = FirstArray1;

    NSArray *FirstArray2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
      @"Turkey",@"Peanut Butter",@"Tuna Salad",@"Chicken Salad",@"Roast Beef",
      @"Vegemite",nil];
    self.Array2 = FirstArray2;

    [super viewDidLoad];
 }

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return[self.Array1 count];
    return[self.Array2 count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
    forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    return [self.Array1 objectAtIndex:row];
    return [self.Array2 objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (component == 0) {
    return[self.Array1 count];
} else if (component == 1) {
    return[self.Array2 count];
} 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I like to manage things...

```
let pickerData = [["column1_1","column1_2","column1_3","column1_4"],
                  ["column2_1","column2_2","column2_3","column2_4"]]

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData[component].count
}
```

The component number references the array, nice and simple.